# NoMethodError in CommentsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im a beginner in rails so i started to follow a tutorial on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html Now im stuck on the 6.4 part when you need to make a comment but i cant figure it out what the problem is. When i want to create a comment im getting this error and oh yeah im on windows

NoMethodError in CommentsController#create

undefined method `title' for # Comment:0x88e4038

this is my comment controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
 http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", only: :destroy
  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
    end
end
```

This is my show.html.erb

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @article.title %>
</p>
 
<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @article.text %>
</p>
 
<h2>Comments</h2>
<%= render @article.comments %>
 
<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
 
<%= link_to 'Edit Article', edit_article_path(@article) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back to Articles', articles_path %>
```

comment.html.erb

```
<p>
  <strong>Commenter:</strong>
  <%= comment.commenter %>
</p>
 
<p>
  <strong>Comment:</strong>
  <%= comment.body %>
</p>
 
<p>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.article, comment],
               method: :delete,
               data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</p>
```

and this is the route

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :articles do
  resources :comments
  end
   root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Comment: have you restart the server? `rails s`

Comment: Show me your `Article` model content

Comment: have you re-run migration after modifying the models?

Comment: yeah i restart the server

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5 }
end

Comment: Show me your `Comment` model content

Comment: class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5 }
end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the tutorial and the comment model has no attribute title. Rails is complaining because you're trying to validate the 'title' attribute in the Comment model:

```
validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
```

Remove this validation.